# What Media Type is encrypted text?

Tags: mime-types, media-type

I'm encrypting a file and saving it in AWS. What Media Type (FKA MIME-type) is encrypted text? "text/plain" doesn't seem right.

Comment: You can make one up (especially since it ought to depend on the encryption mechanism / format)

Comment: Or use octet-stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
application/octet-stream
```

which is intended for arbitrary binary data - perfect for an encrypted file that by definition can't be interpreted. ([RFC2046](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt))